# Is it possible that my C++ program accidentally crash Visual Studio or Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, crash

I created a Visual Studio C++ project, write a game (about 10K-lines).

Yesterday, I compile and ran it in release mode, then I got some access violation error.

My program doesn't have any virus-like command, the closest one is just the array access, 
so I think it came from array-index-out-of-bound.

Therefore, I aborted my program - using STOP button - and edit my code, test it again - F5 (release mode, not-optimized).

This happened around 10-20 times - crash & debug ; my happy life cycle.

When I shut down, Windows 7 created a popup error about access violation.
(It has sometimes happened before, but has never caused any serious long-term affect.)

### **Problem**

Today, after I turned on the computer, it began to act strangely

- Windows and Visual Studio start up a little slower. (I may be biased.)
- Windows task bar (that has the start button) is quite non-responsive. (obvious, happen only once)
- Visual Studio : some shortcuts (Ctrl K + Ctrl O to switch .cpp /.h) not work anymore except it open a file instead (look like it recognize only Ctrl O).
- Visual Studio : I can't assign any shortcut that has 2 Ctrl button (e.g. Ctrl xxx + Ctrl xxx)
- I test with on-screen keyboard, after a bit of testing, my computer crashed. (mouse cursor disappear)

After I turned on my computer again - avoid opening Visual Studio, my computer act as almost normal, but alt+tab not work anymore.

Note that I didn't install any new software in the last 7 days.

### **Question**

Is it possible that bug / crash of my C++ program (always run within Visual Studio) can destroy some structure of Visual Studio or OS unintentionally?

If so, is there any setting of Windows / Visual Studio to prevent it?

Comment: I suppose it's rather impossible. The only thing your program could have done is damaging some system files or visual studio files opening them directly (if it has appropriate UAC level).
I think your problems are caused not by your Visual c++ app

Comment: I sometimes have the problem, when using industry-cameras for example (with the manufacturers dlls), that by aborting the execution in VS, it crashes. Imo it's the debugger that crashes and therefore VS too. Not sure if Im right. Furthermore if Im using low-level libraries which communicate with specific hardware on kernel-level I was also able to create some bluescreens.

Comment: @Robert  I could also achieve bluescreen by using infinite-loop shader (glsl), but never from simple things like index-out-of-bound.   In your case, did it yield any affect after your turned on the computer again?

Comment: @javaLover Never experienced any issue after reboot, however, that doesnt mean there arent any. I think it depends on which level you are 'working'. When interacting with hardware interfaces it could be that the hardware itself causes problems (even with a index-out-of-bound exception), with both software and system. In my experience I had the most issues when operating on kernel level (i.e. EtherCat, industry cameras, ecc.)

Comment: I think it the problems aren't caused by your app. I usually use the stop button method 20 times a day and the only 'problem' I get is that I don't close my file handles. After a reboot all is fine again. Unless you used some system files of course, then that might be a problem...

Comment: One of my first c++ + OpenGL programs (run on Windows XP) changed my desktop appearance to complete nonsense just before crashing with an access violation. Since Win7 is related to XP, I  could well imagine that an app, independent of it being started from VS or from anywhere else, can do damage at data it should not have access to. Mine was actually started from Code blocks. Nevertheless, I admit that it is rather unlikely. I've experienced something like this exactly once in 14 years of coding.